# React Redux action not entering into dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have seen some similar questions to this one, but I'm not entirely sure if I understand how mapDispatchToProps, bindActionCreators and connect work and so am unsure where I'm going wrong.

At the moment, my recordFullTimeScoreAnswer function is being called, but when it enters the function nothing happens after the return line. The console.log is not printed and there aren't any errors

Component

```
renderNextQuestionArrow(question: Question) {
        const p = this.props;
        const s = this.state;

        return (
            <div onClick={ () => { p.recordFullTimeScoreAnswer(s.homeScore, s.awayScore, p.question, p.questionIndex, p.user, p.configs) } }>
                <Arrow direction="right" action={ () => { p.showNextQuestion() } }/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Container

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { recordFullTimeScoreAnswer, showNextQuestion } from '../actions';

render() {
    return(
        <FullTimeScoreActive
                imgSrc={imgSrc}
                user={user}
                answerStatus={answerStatus}
                question={question}
                showNextQuestion={showNextQuestion}
                recordFullTimeScoreAnswer={recordFullTimeScoreAnswer}
                questionIndex={questionIndex}
                total={total}
                configs={configs}
            />
    )
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ recordFullTimeScoreAnswer, showNextQuestion }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FullTimeScoreContainer);

export { FullTimeScoreContainer }
```

Action

```
export function recordFullTimeScoreAnswer(
    homeScore: number,
    awayScore: number,
    question: Object,
    questionIndex: number,
    user: User,
    configs: Configs
) {
    console.log("outside record answer");
    return (dispatch: Function) => {
        console.log("inside record answer");

        let uri = configs.baseAPIPath + '/questions/';

        if ( user.loggedIn ) {
            fetchWithAuth(uri, 'POST', answer, user.tokens, configs.clientId, dispatch, false, v.questionId).then( (data) => {
                if (data) {
                    dispatch({
                        type: RECORD_ANSWER_SUCCESS,
                        payload: { questionIndex, answerId }
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The last thing I see is the "outside record answer" log but never the "inside record answer" one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is in this line:

```
recordFullTimeScoreAnswer = { recordFullTimeScoreAnswer }
```

Here you are directly passing the action defined inside the action file, not the one which was passed to component in props by `mapDispatchToProps` method, In you case you are always calling the outer method, inner method never got called, also `recordFullTimeScoreAnswer` will not get the access of `dispatch`.

Use this:

```
recordFullTimeScoreAnswer={this.props.recordFullTimeScoreAnswer}
```

**Note:**

The way you wrote will print the inner console if you write it like this:

```
recordFullTimeScoreAnswer = {recordFullTimeScoreAnswer()}      // notice `()`
```

But it will throw the error also.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been working on that all morning and was getting nowhere!